# Swagger CodeGen, make Proxies remove certain elements and be Simplified

Tags: angular, typescript, swashbuckle, swagger-codegen, angular10

Is there a way to Auto Generate proxies with Swagger Io Codegen Editor, while removing certain elements? We are converting C# Apis to Angular Typescript Proxies.

1. I have 4 methods below,
2. Do not require Authentication if the statement
3. Nor do I need HeadersAccept

https://editor.swagger.io/

Original Proxy:

```
    public getUserDepartment(departmentId: number, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<GetUserResponse>;
    public getUserDepartment(departmentId: number, observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<GetUserResponse>>;
    public getUserDepartment(departmentId: number, observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpEvent<GetUserResponse>>;
    public getUserDepartment(departmentId: number, observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false ): Observable<any> {

        if (departmentId === null || departmentId === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter departmentId was null or undefined when calling getUserDepartment.');
        }

        let headers = this.defaultHeaders;

        // authentication (Token) required
        if (this.configuration.apiKeys && this.configuration.apiKeys["Authorization"]) {
            headers = headers.set('Authorization', this.configuration.apiKeys["Authorization"]);
        }

        // to determine the Accept header
        let httpHeaderAccepts: string[] = [
            'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true',
            'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false',
            'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal',
            'application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true',
            'application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false',
            'application/json;odata.metadata=full',
            'application/json;odata.metadata=none;odata.streaming=true',
            'application/json;odata.metadata=none;odata.streaming=false',
            'application/json;odata.metadata=none',
            'application/json;odata.streaming=true',
            'application/json;odata.streaming=false',
            'application/json',
            'application/xml',
            'application/prs.odatatestxx-odata',
            'text/plain',
            'text/json'
        ];
        const httpHeaderAcceptSelected: string | undefined = this.configuration.selectHeaderAccept(httpHeaderAccepts);
        if (httpHeaderAcceptSelected != undefined) {
            headers = headers.set('Accept', httpHeaderAcceptSelected);
        }

        // to determine the Content-Type header
        const consumes: string[] = [
        ];

        return this.httpClient.request<GetUserResponse>('get',`${this.basePath}/api/Users/department/${encodeURIComponent(String(departmentId))}`,
            {
                withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
                headers: headers,
                observe: observe,
                reportProgress: reportProgress
            }
        );
    }
```

**Final Intended Result:**

```
    public getUserDepartment(departmentId: number) {

        if (departmentId === null || departmentId === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter departmentId was null or undefined when calling getUserDepartment.');
        }
    
        return this.httpClient.request<GetUserResponse>('get',`${this.basePath}/api/Users/department/${encodeURIComponent(String(departmentId))}`,
            {}
        );
    }
```

The team has over 1000+ Api methods to convert , looking for simplified code